# math domain error no PYTHON

Tags: python

Eu sei que se a raiz for menor do que zero ela não ira existir, mas, algo acontece, mesmo eu implementando que se o valor de delta for menor do que zero é para escrever o erro ele ainda continua mostrando "math domain error" não sei o motivo. Deixo o código aqui em baixo para melhor julgamento.

```
a = float(input("Insira um valor para A: "))

b = float(input("Insira um valor para B: "))

c = float(input("Insira um valor para C: "))



d = b ** 2 - 4 * a * c

print("Delta: ",d)

delta = math.sqrt(d)

print("Raiz quadrada de delta: ",delta)



if d > 0:

x1 = (-b + delta)/ (2*a)

x2 = (-b - delta)/ (2*a)

print("X1 = ", x1, "X2 = ", x2)

elif d == 0:

x = -b / (2*a)

print("Valor de x = ",x)

elif d < 0:

print("Essa raiz é menor do que zero")
```

Comment: Comece por corrigir a indentação para que jogue a 100% com o código tal como o tem escrito, assim como colocar os imports que está a utilizar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro acontece exatamente nessa linha:

```
delta = math.sqrt(d)
```

E acontece porque você manda que ele calcule a raiz quadrada de `d`, que pode ser negativo, antes de verificar se ele realmente é negativo.

Você tem que primeiro verificar se ele é negativo, e só se não for tentar calcular a raiz:

```
import math

a = float(input("Insira um valor para A: "))
b = float(input("Insira um valor para B: "))
c = float(input("Insira um valor para C: "))

d = b ** 2 - 4 * a * c
print("Delta: ", d)


if d > 0:
    delta = math.sqrt(d)
    print("Raiz quadrada de delta: ", delta)
    x1 = (-b + delta) / (2 * a)
    x2 = (-b - delta) / (2 * a)
    print("X1 = ", x1, "X2 = ", x2)

elif d == 0:
    delta = math.sqrt(d)
    print("Raiz quadrada de delta: ", delta)
    x = -b / (2 * a)
    print("Valor de x = ", x)

elif d < 0:
    print("Essa raiz é menor do que zero")
```

Answer (score 1):

Sei que isto foi a muito tempo, porem estou aprendendo e utlizei em 3.9 e tive que mudar os (d) para (delta) e math.sqrt(d) para sqrt(delta):

```
from math import sqrt

""" codigo original, tive que inserir valores para que sublimetext me deixe probar
a = int(input("Digite o valor de A: "))
b = int(input("Digite o valor de B: "))
c = int(input("Digite o valor de C: "))
"""

a = 2
b = 400
c = 6


delta = b**2 - 4*a*c
raiz_delta = sqrt(delta)

if delta > 0:
    delta = sqrt(delta)
    print("Raiz quadrada de delta: ", delta)
    x1 = (-b + delta) / (2 * a)
    x2 = (-b - delta) / (2 * a)
    print("X1 = ", x1, "X2 = ", x2)

elif delta == 0:
    delta = sqrt(delta)
    print("Raiz quadrada de delta: ", delta)
    x = -b / (2 * a)
    print("Valor de x = ", x)

elif delta < 0:
    print("Essa raiz é menor do que zero")
```