# For dentro de outro For

Tags: python, loop, for, match

Pessoal estou precisando rodar um for dentro de outro for mas não estou conseguindo. Preciso armazenar o valor do resultado dentro de uma variável. Não conheço da linguagem python, acredito que esse seja o maior problema. Segue o que tenho tentado para armazenar o resultado.

```py
import math

perimeter = [18, 24, 14]

area = [24, 36, 10]

lista2 = []

for i in perimeter:
    for x in area:
        d = {}   
        d = print(((i/2)+math.sqrt((i/2))**2-4*x))/2))
        lista2.append = (d)
print(lista2)
```

Alguém consegue me propor uma solução para o problema? Pois não consigo chegar ao resultado.

Answer (score 1):

1. Eu não sei se foi um erro na formulação da pergunta, mas o código está sem identação. Na linguagem Python, o que define o que está dentro de uma estrutura de código, como o for, é sua identação interna.
2. A função *append*, para listas, recebe um valor que será adicionado à lista. Da forma como ela está sendo usada, é como se você estivesse passando o valor de retorno dela para a variável *d*, o que não faz sentido, já que ela não retorna nada. A utilização correta seria da seguinte maneira:

   lista2.append(d)
3. Há um erro de sintaxe no cálculo da variável *d*. Corrigindo, fica da seguinte maneira:

   d = ((i/2)+math.sqrt((i/2))**2-4*x)/2

O código completo fica assim:

```
import math

perimeter = [18, 24, 14]

area = [24, 36, 10]

lista2 = []

for i in perimeter:
    for x in area:
    
        d = {}
    
        d = ((i/2)+math.sqrt((i/2))**2-4*x)/2
    
        lista2.append(d)

print(lista2)
```

[Veja rodando no repl.it](https://repl.it/@Jvsierra_/For-dentro-de-outro-For-StackOverflow#main.py)

Comment: Ocorreu um erro na formatação da pergunta sim, mas foi ótima a resposta, consegui resolver o problema. Acabei percebendo que não precisava de um for dentro de outro, mas somente de usar um zip para as duas listas. Mas ainda permaneço com um problema na sintaxe do cálculo da variável. Através do python consigo escrever da seguinte forma: d = ((24/2)-math.sqrt((24/2)**2-4*32))/2. O print retorna 4. Mas quando coloco dentro do for, retorna um ValueError: math domain error. Como corrigir esse erro?

Comment: Thallys, na variável há a utilização da função *sqrt*, que calcula a raíz quadrada. Esse erro pode acontecer quando o parâmetro dessa função é um número negativo, o que retornaria um erro de domínio. Faça um *debug* simples (pode até imprimir na tela o valor que é passado para a função *sqrt*) e verifique que isso acontece. Dê uma olhada nessa pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/295455/math-domain-error-no-python